# A person who threatens with legal troubles

Tags: word-choice

What are some best words/phrases/sentences to describe a person who warns you of complaining to authorities or sue in court for trivial things when they appear to be breaking the law, even though there is no intention.

For example, a spouse accusing his/her partner of holding hostage when asked to stay at home for the evening, Or that they have threat for life if the other person just clenches their fist in anger etc.

Comment: It's not clear in your examples who the parties are and which is threatening legal action. I also don't think there's a single word or phrase that would cover these different examples.

Comment: I am looking for a general word choice for such a person, I provided examples for additional clarity.

Comment: to threaten legal action

Comment: The title and the 2nd set of examples are a disconnect...

Comment: I don't get it, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour related to your title is **litigious**. You might also qualify it better as merely **threateningly litigious** when there is no real intention to go to law, as in your two examples.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/litigious)
> *litigious*:
> too ready to take disagreements to a court of law so that a legal decision can be made about them

Comment: And *torte-happy*.